# Sonarqube: reordering published build results

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am publishing build results to Sonarqube, with jenkins.
Each commit on git is triggering a jenkins build.

My problem is that build duration is not deterministic so build #2 can finish before build #1.
Consequently, results are published to Sonar in wrong order and differential view shows wrong results.
For example, if i corrected a unit test in build #2, results of build #1 will tell me that test is failing again.

Build result version is setted and it should be used to order builds instead of publication date.
Is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube platform is going to process the analysis reports in the order it receives them. It has no way of knowing anything about your Jenkins build number.

Your best bet is to enable the Throttle Concurrent Builds option to make sure that each new job waits its turn. That's the only way to ensure the order you expect.

Comment: I setted build number through this option: -Dsonar.projectVersion
I though maybe Sonar could use it.
But i'm Ok with your answer.